# ngx-charts: Is there a way to add custom vertical line or popup tied to a certain y-axis value?

Tags: d3.js, ngx-charts

What the title says. I would like to add something constantly visible (line, tooltip, ...) which is connected to a value on y-axis (in this case to a date). Is there any way to do this in any shape or form?

Symbolic picture:
[image]

Comment: Found a solution for this yet?